# width and height of image are zero because of asynchronous image loading in objective c iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, ios10

i am trying to get image width and height out of dispatch_async function but it gives zero result.

Below is my code

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://url%@",[[arrayEvents objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"image"]]]];

                //NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
                UIImage *images = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:imageData];
                CGFloat height = images.size.height;
                CGFloat width = images.size.width;
                ratio_2=scrrenwidth/width;
                scaledHeight_2=height*ratio_2;

                 img_vw2.image=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

 });

 NSLog(@"%f",scaledHeight_2);
```

When I print Inside the `dispatch_async` I got correct Image height and width but when I print outside the `dispatch_async` it gives me `0` as a value.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Run the code you *need outside dispatch_async* inside the block. By the way, never load data from a remote URL with synchronous method `dataWithContentsOfURL`. It will block the thread, in case of the main thread this causes bad user experience.

Answer (score 0):

if your `NSLog` call is immediately after the `dispatch_async`, then it will always show zero - just move that print to inside the completion handler

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using
[GCD](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html). That means you telling the compiler to do 2 task at a single time. So first he compiles the code outside the GCD block i.e. `dispatch_asyn`later it compiles the GCD code.

For confirmation of my answer you can put an break point and you can check or you can check by by which data is printed first in console.

In your case data is fetched in the GCD, so until it doen't get data it always be 0.

Hope it helps you to understand what actually you have done in your code..